# Restricting buffers to popup in a particular window on emacs

Tags: emacs, window, buffer

How can I redirect some buffers to popup in a particular window? For example, when you are using the shell, and you press `<TAB>`, a `*completions*` buffer will popup (usually) on a right window... but how can I make this buffer to always popup on another window?

I'd prefer solutions that doesn't involve installing new libraries (even though, programming my own elisp function would be neat).

I'm asking this, because when I use emacs, O like to split it into 3 windows:

The left window is where I code, let's call this the plotting window. The right top window, is where compilation messages will pop-up, let's call it the information window. The right bottom window is where I use the shell, let's call it the shell window. When I use the shell window, and press `<TAB>` for completions proposals, the `*completions*` buffer will popup on my plotting window, instead of on my information window.

Until now, I have tried just pressing `q` when I go to my plotting window, but this is becoming annoying, because it wont always return to the code I was working in, so I have to C-right until I find my code, or C-x b (if I can remember the name of the file I was editing).

Comment: The functions that generate your special buffers like Completions will need to be modified to use display-buffer or its family of functions.

Comment: Tangentially, see `winner-mode` which I just commented on here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20809590/324105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to dedicate the plotting window and the shell window to their buffers. If you have already installed emacs-goodies then you can use <kbd>M-x dedicated-mode</kbd> for that purpose.

In the case that the plotting window and the shell window are dedicated emacs only uses the information window to pop-up new buffers.

I for myself use a menu-item that I added to the Buffers menu:

```lisp
(defun window-dedicated-toggle ()
  "Toggle wether window is dedicated to buffer or not."
  (interactive)
  (message
   (if (window-dedicated-p)
       (progn
     (set-window-dedicated-p nil nil)
     "Window not dedicated.")
     (progn
       (set-window-dedicated-p nil t)
       "Window dedicated."))))

(easy-menu-add-item nil '("Buffers") ["Toggle Dedicate Window To Buffer" window-dedicated-toggle t])
```

Comment: thanks! dedicated-mode did the trick... I just used M-x dedicated-mode to fix the window to it's buffer, and M-x dedicated-mode to unfix it and open a new file into it.