# Emacs killing buffers

Tags: emacs

(Emacs newbie here)

Sometimes a *Help* buffer gets opened in my emacs editor. It opens in a different pane, splitting the current window into two halves vertically.

When I use C-k buffer-name, to kill a buffer (say Help), some other buffer (say *scratch*) gets opened automatically in that pane.

Is it possible to revert to my previous configuration, after a random buffer (Help or Debug..) gets opened.

My previous configuration would be to go back to a single window with no panes

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can use `q` to close the help buffer.

Comment: I set F11 to delete-window and F12 to delete-other- windows.

Comment: @lawlist, I have the same two functions for this situation, only on `C-F9` and `F9`.

Answer (score 3):

To revert to the previous window configuration after any arbitrary change(s), you should enable `winner-mode` in your .emacs file:

```
(winner-mode 1)
```

Then you can use <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> (repeatedly, if necessary) to undo window configuration changes with `winner-undo`.

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><right></kbd> calls `winner-redo` which returns you to the most recent configuration (immediately; not in single steps the like the 'undo' command).

Winner mode is the key to never ever getting annoyed by Emacs creating an unwanted window, but it also lets *you* do things you wouldn't have done before (for instance <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to maximise one of your windows temporarily for easier reading, because getting back all the windows you just deleted is now trivial).

Obviously this is also incredibly useful if you *accidentally* mess up your window config!

Comment: Winner-mode is a real winner here. Very useful especially when debugging lisps (Clojure in my case) where dynamic typing potentially brings up a lot of runtime errors and therefore "popup" windows.

Answer (score 0):

Hello to revert back to one buffer you must hit <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> while standing in the buffer you want to keep. And to switch between frames <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>

Comment: (The last part is not quite correct. `C-x o` selects the other  Emacs window, not frame.  `C-x 5 o` selects the other frame.)